# Python Lottery number and checker

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a random number generator for any number of numbers in a line and then repeating those random numbers until a "target" number is reached. 
The user will enter both the number of numbers in the sequence and the sequence they are shooting for. The program will run the random numbers over and over until the target sequence is hit, then the program will spit out the number of repetitions it took. 
My problem is that it keeps going on forever, seemingly never hitting the break function because num doesn't equal target or something. 
So far I have this and i think i am pretty close

```
#Module to get amount of numbers in the sequence 
def getRange():
    Range =int(input("How many digits in your number?"))
    return Range
#Target Sequence input
def getTarget():
    Target= []
    Target =input("What is your target sequence?")

    return Target

def lotteryNo(Range):
    import random
    integer = []

    for number in range(0 , Range):
        integer.append(random.randint(0, 9))  
    return integer

def printDigits(Range,Target):

    print("Your target list is",Target) 
    for rep in range(10000000):
        num=(lotteryNo(Range))
        print(num) 
        if num == Target:
            rep=rep + 1
            print("The number of repetitions is",rep) 
            break


        else:
            rep=rep+1 



def main():
    Range=getRange()
    Target=getTarget() 
    printDigits(Range,Target)
main()
#End
```

Comment: for the last `else:` statement you could just do `rep += 1` looks nicer.

Comment: Right, the problem.. The problem is that the condition num == Target never seems to activate and the program goes on forever

Comment: I found your problem you need to remove the `[ ]` from around the numbers in `lotteryNo()` for example 5 cannot equal [5]

Comment: okay sorry where exactly should i do that?

Comment: I'm testing it for a fix

Comment: Did you get an answer or do I need to keep trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your comparison is that you're testing `Target` which is a string against `num` which is a list of integers. That will never match, no matter what integers and what string you're dealing with. You need to compare two like-types to get a meaningful result.

It looks like you wanted your `getTarget` function to return a list, since you're initializing `Target` to an empty string. However, when you overwrite it with `Target = input(...)`, the list is discarded.

You probably want something like `Target = list(map(int, input()))`, which converts each character of the input string to an integer and then packs them all into a list. Another way of writing that would be `Target = [int(digit) for digit in input()]`.

One further suggestion, unrelated to your current issue: Python's common naming convention is to use `lower_case_names_with_underscores` for variable and function names, reserving `UpperCaseNames` for classes. You don't have to follow this convention, but it's probably a good idea if you're going to share your code with anyone. You can read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more style suggestions.

Comment: Thank you i will try that! That makes a lot of sense... I thought they were different types of data, now it is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because one of your numbers is a list and the other is a string from input.

Change Target to get an `int`

```
def getTarget():
    Target =int(input("What is your target sequence?"))
    return Target
```

Change lotteryNo to get an `int`

```
def lotteryNo(Range):
    import random
    integer = 0
    for number in range(0 , Range):
        integer += random.randint(0, 9) * (10**number)
    return integer
```

And your `if num == Target:` comparison should now work as it is comparing two variables of the same type.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense too. What is the (10**number) there for though?

Comment: `**` is Exponentiation in Python. It's the same as 10^number. It's there to add the digits by prepending. So it adds a multiple of 1, then a multiple of 10, then 100 and so forth. This eventually constructs the`int` you want. You could also do this by having large parameter for `randint` but I chose this as it was closer to your original code.

Comment: TL;DR: It makes each `randint` be added as a new digit.

Comment: Oh i see.. so if it generates a 1 it will be on the end, and then if its a 2 it will be in the tens place because it is multiplied by 10 and the next number will be in the hundreds... Got it. Thank you this helped a lot